# Cloud Functions: Delete file on Cloud Storage when Firestore document is deleted

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I have a cloud function which listens for onDelete events. When a document is deleted, I also want an associated file on the storage to be deleted. 
Currently I have only the download-url (https link) stored as a field in the document.

How can I select the file within the function? Is this possible or should I store the storage location (path) of the file inside the document and use that to do:

```
storage.bucket(<my-bucket>).file(<path>).delete()
```

Comment: The default bucket should be available from the Admin SDK with `var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();`. If that doesn't work for you, please update your question with the [minimum code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thx, for answering! I use the '@google-cloud/storage' package to get the bucket. I couldnt find information how to use the admin package with firestore in the official documentation. However I got the bucket, the challenge is how to get the right file.

Comment: Information on how to get the default Cloud Storage bucket with the Admin SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#use_a_default_bucket

Comment: Ty! What is the benefit of using the admin sdk and not modules like @google-cloud/storage ?

Comment: The Admin SDK is pre-initialized to know about your Firebase/GCP project, so already "knows" your project's default bucket. In other words: one benefit is precisely what you were asking about. :-)

Comment: What this question is asking for is whether or not cloud functions have the ability to retrieve a storage reference with just the download URL, as it is possible to do this on the web client with firebase.storage().refFromURL(url)
but not with the admin SDK, it seems. Overall, it seems the storage SDK for cloud functions is incomplete and it's unclear when it will be more properly integrated into Firebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Cloud Storage SDK doesn't have a way to convert an HTTPS download URL into a file path in your storage bucket.  If you need to know the path to a file in Cloud Storage, you should store that path as another field in your database.  This will make it easy to reach back into your storage bucket to delete the file when needed.